# Pin point where the optional is returning nil

Tags: swift, xcode

The output of my code is "Optional(46 bytes)"
how can I pint point which variable is returning nil so I can adjust it.

Comment: use breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

Open breakpoint navigator from the right panel of XCode. See following image.

[image: BreakPoints]

Then from bottom left corner click on **+**, this will show you popup. From that select **Swift Error Breakpoint** & **Exception Breakpoint...**.

After that keep debugging activated and run project, this will let you go to exact point from where application crashing due to nil value.